If $n\in\Bbb N$ is factor of 144, and $xy=n$ , then no. of ordered pairs of $(x,y)$?- ($x,y\in\Bbb N$)
Question- If $n\in\Bbb N$ is a factor of $144$, and $xy=n$ , then no. of ordered pairs of $(x,y)$ are- (x,y are natural numbers)
My solution- as we know $144 = 
2^4\cdot3^2$
We can take all the $15$ factors and then check the number in each of the $15$ factors. But this a little length and not efficient if they are numbers larger than $144$. Any shorter approach?

Choudhary is answer 90?

Yes, it is so....

Any factor $n$ of $144$ is of the form $2^a\cdot 3^b$, where $0 \leq a \leq 4$ and $0 \leq b \leq 2$. If $xy=n$, then $x=2^{x_1}\cdot3^{x_2}$ and $y=2^{y_1} \cdot 3^{y_2}$. Thus,
$$xy=2^{x_1+y_1}\cdot3^{x_2+y_2}=2^{a} \cdot 3^b=n.$$
This gives us
\begin{align}
x_1+y_1&=a \tag{1}\label{eq1}\\
x_2+y_2&=b \tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}
We are interested in the number of non-negative integer solutions to this pair of equations. Recall (stars and bars result): the number of non-negative integer solutions for
$$z_1+z_2+\dotsb+z_r=k$$
is given by $\binom{k+r-1}{r-1}$. Using this, we get the number of non-negative integer solutions for equation \eqref{eq1} as $\binom{a+1}{1}=a+1$, likewise for equation \eqref{eq2}, we get $b+1$. Thus, the number of solutions for the system is $(a+1)(b+1)$.
Now we let $0 \leq a \leq 4$ and $0 \leq b\leq 2$, to get
$$\sum_{a=0}^{a=4}\sum_{b=0}^{b=2}(a+1)(b+1)=90$$
NOTE: The counting for $x_1+y_1=a$ can be done easily without invoking the star and bars result. However, I am doing this to cover similar problems where we may have more factors.

You can greatly simplify this by considering solutions to $xyz = 144$, of which there are ${ 6 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2} = 90$ solutions.
